# Automatic Reload Nginx on Config Update - OOB Solution

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am looking to reload my nginx service automatically whenever my "/etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf" file gets updated. Is there a way that nginx provides out of the box to do this ?

Note - I have gone through a lot of links to find the automatic way, but all I find was some shell script to keep on observing the file change and reload nginx once the file gets updated.